# How do I execute datetime based query in Objective C(Mobile SDK for iOS - SFRestAPI)?

Tags: rest-api, mobilesdk, ios

This is what I've tried so far.

I get the current timestamp, format it to the Date format and append it to the query.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];

NSString *lastModifiedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSMutableString *query = [[NSMutableString alloc ] initWithString:@"select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact LastModifiedDate > "];

[query appendString: lastModifiedDate];

SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery: query];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

This is the error I get.

```
2013-06-21 16:59:07.209 FMDB01[4624:c07] SFRestAPI::send: <SFRestRequest 0x9ca5380 
endpoint: /services/data 
method: GET 
path: /v23.0/query 
queryParams: {
 "q" : "select Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact WHERE LastModifiedDate > 2013-06-21 04:59:07"
} >
2013-06-21 16:59:08.517 FMDB01[4624:c07] error: Error Domain=com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain Code=999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain error 999.)" UserInfo=0x9ca9a70 {message= 
LastModifiedDate > 2013-06-21 04:59:07
                                     ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:162
line 1:162 no viable alternative at character '<EOF>', errorCode=MALFORMED_QUERY}
2013-06-21 16:59:08.517 FMDB01[4624:c07] request:didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain Code=999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain error 999.)" UserInfo=0x9ca9a70 {message= 
LastModifiedDate > 2013-06-21 04:59:07
                                     ^
```

I tried passing the DateTime field in single quotes and I get an error saying `value of filter criterion for field 'LastModifiedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes, errorCode=INVALID_FIELD`.

Any help on how to proceed will help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Datetime` format that Salesforce uses cannot be formatted using `NSDateFormatter`. MobileSDK has a util class `SFDateUtil` that can be used to convert `NSDate` into formatted string.

```
NSString *dateInString = [SFDateUtil toSOQLDateTimeString:[NSDate date] isDateTime:true];
```

This gives the datetime in `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z`. This String can be used in query. The same method can be used for Date too.

Answer (score 4):

Try to modify your `LastModifiedDate` to the following format:

```
2013-06-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

So add `T00:00:00.000Z` to the `2013-06-21` without white space (generally format it like this: `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.000Z`)